# "status":415, "status":"UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, postman

I'm using Curl to call json API with following as:

```
curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"niceSessionKey\": \"S202320220722145915340287\",\"fiCode\": \"B100000022\",\"taskCode\": \"KYC_VC2_RSLT\",\"appNumber\": \"APPL000000000000999\",\"customerNumber\": \"12345678\",\"mobilePhoneNumber\": \"0966688526\"}" https://100.113.125.128:8080/api/KYT_VC7_RSLT
```

But when i run it return result from server following as:

```
"status":"UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported","errors":["application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 media type is not supported. Supported media types are application/octet-stream, text/plain, application/xml, text/xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/*+xml, multipart/form-data, application/json, application/*+json, */*"]}
```

I have set Content-Type is application/json, but i don't why it still return get result error. How to fix the problem ?

Comment: Request looks fine. Might not be you. Might be the server.

Comment: Add `-v` to show what headers it is sending. Possibly you have an invisible character or homoglyph in your `-H` causing the default content-type from `-d` (which is www-form) to be used instead.

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085, could you tell me more detail ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    @PostMapping(
  path = "/web/feedback",
  consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
```